# How can i extract jquery parameters from url?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to extract the "data:" for station listed bellow from this url http://swe-sso.dlr.de/Ionospheric_Perturbations/Rate_Of_Change_Of_TEC_Index/mean_ROTI_Europe/latest/mean_ROTI_Europe.json

```
{
  "properties": {
    "rcv": "BUCU00ROU0_EUREF",
    "sat": "G24",
    "roti": 0.508,
    "azimuth_deg": 168.4,
    "elevation_deg": 20.99
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      25.34,
      45.15
    ]
  }
}
```

"Data:" is the main index for stations data

what is the correct syntax to do that with js?

Comment: Am I correct that you are receiving the desired JSON response from that endpoint?

Comment: The data is not in station indentifier , but is there in that json indexed as main "data:" - 0, 1,2,3,4...after station indentification codes.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. The example JSON you give in the question has no `data` attribute. Rather than posting a link to the data, consider editing your question to include the relevant parts of the data. Some context would also be useful; where is this Javascript running? Is it a web app? A command line tool?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `sat` and not `station`, as that doesn't exist in your example. You could access it like this with JavaScript by assigning it to a variable:

```
var sat = yourJSONobj["properties"]["sat"]
```

Here's an example printing that object in that array:

```js
yourJSON = { "properties":{ "rcv":"BUCU00ROU0_EUREF", "sat":"G24", "roti":0.508, "azimuth_deg":168.4, "elevation_deg":20.99 } }, { "type":"Feature", "geometry":{ "type":"Point", "coordinates":[ 25.34, 45.15 ] } }

document.getElementById("json").innerHTML +=JSON.stringify(yourJSON["properties"]["sat"]);
```

```html
<p id="json"></p>
```

edit: cleaned up code

Comment: Thank you for this answer but i don't point to the station indentifiers, the data are in other index like "data:" bellow station indentifiers see the full json response (i think)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to point you in the right direction here, but you'll need to still do some reading. To clarify, you appear to be asking how you can use jQuery to load some JSON data, and then pull out parts of it. I'm inferring this by looking at the URL you provided.

1. First thing you'll want to know is how to get that JSON that's sitting behind the URL into a JavaScript object. You should look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ to get started there. That will tell you how to load the JSON.
2. Next, you appear to want to build a new JavaScript object that has only a small subset of the data in the much larger response. That's pretty much just pulling out the bits by traversing the paths in the returned JSON. In this case though, there's a lot of data, and there's a lot of repetition. If you're looking to grab a specific piece of that data, you can either write some code to loop through elements in one of the arrays that contains the data you want (maybe the metadata.integrated_gnss_stations.features array), or using something like JSONPath (http://jsonpath.com/) to easily traverse into it.

If you use JSONPath, you could use a path like

```
metadata.integrated_gnss_stations.features..[?(@.rcv=='BUCU00ROU0_EUREF')]
```

… to get an array of all 5 satellites for the items where rcv == "BUCU00ROU0_EUREF".  You can then take that return and project it into whatever other form you'd like.